# how can I change the value of a variable(dy) based on each tick of the timer?

Tags: c#, timer

Now I am reading a book C # Programming for the Absolute Beginner
In Chapter 7, Section workouts, which put it.My question is that 
The Interval property of a timer is specified in milliseconds, not ticks.
Now, how can I change the value of a variable(dy) based on each tick

> Modify the difficulty level of the Lunar Lander game. There are several ways you could
>   tweak the code. Perhaps you could change gravity by modifying the change in dy during
>   each tick of the timer. You could also adjust how much dx and dy change during each key
>   press or how fast time progresses by modifying the timer’s interval. Another easy change
>   would be to modify the size of the landing pad or the lander.

[image]

```
public partial class theForm : Form
    {

    private double x, y; //will show new position of lander 
    private double dx, dy; //diffrence in x and y
    private int fuel = 100; //how much fuel is left
    private int ships = 3; // number of ships player has 
    private int score = 0; //the player's current score
    private int level = 1;
    public theForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        initGame();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //account for gravity
        dy += 0.5;

        //increment score for being alive
        score += 100;

        //show ordinary (no flames) lander
        picLander.Image = myPics.Images[0];


        //call helper methods to handle details
        moveShip();
        checkLanding();
        showStats();
    }//end timer tick



    private void showStats()
    {
        //display the statistics
        lblDx.Text = "dx: " + dx;
        lblDy.Text = "dy: " + dy;
        lblFuel.Text = "fuel: " + fuel;
        lblShips.Text = "ships: " + ships;
        lblScore.Text = "score: " + score;
    }//end showStats

    private void checkLanding()
    {
        //get rectangle from the objects

        Rectangle rLander = picLander.Bounds;
        Rectangle rPlatform = picPlatform.Bounds;

        //look for an interesection
        if (rLander.IntersectsWith(rPlatform))
        {
            //it's either a crash or a landing

            //turn off the timer for a moment
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            if (Math.Abs(dx) < 3)
            {
                //horizontal speed ok
                if (Math.Abs(dy) < 5)
                {
                    //vertical speed ok
                    if (Math.Abs(rLander.Bottom - rPlatform.Top) < 3)
                    {
                        //landing on top of platform
                        MessageBox.Show("Good Landing!");
                        lblLevel.Text=Convert.ToString(level++);
                        fuel += 30;
                        score += 1000;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //not on top of platform
                        MessageBox.Show("You have to land on top.");
                        killShip();
                    }//end vertical if
                }
                else
                {
                    //dy too large
                    MessageBox.Show("Too much vertical velocity!");
                    killShip();
                } // end vertical if
            }
            else
            {
                //dx too large
                MessageBox.Show("too much horizontal velocity");
                killShip();
            }//end horiz if
             //reset the lander
            initGame();
        }//end if


    }//end checkLanding


    private void initGame()
    {
        //re-initializes the game
        Random roller = new Random();

        int platX, platY;

        //find random dx,dy values for lander
        dx = Convert.ToDouble(roller.Next(5) - 2);
        dy = Convert.ToDouble(roller.Next(5) - 2);

        //place lander randomly on form
        x = Convert.ToDouble(roller.Next(this.ClientSize.Width));
        y = Convert.ToDouble(roller.Next(this.ClientSize.Height));

        //place platform randomly on form (but make sure it appears)
        platX = roller.Next(this.ClientSize.Width - picPlatform.Width);
        platY = roller.Next(this.ClientSize.Height - picPlatform.Height);
        picPlatform.Location = new Point(platX, platY);

        //turn on timer
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }//end initGame

    private void killShip()
    {
        //kill off a ship,check for end of game
        DialogResult answer;
        ships--;
        if (ships <= 0)
        {
            //game is over
            answer = MessageBox.Show("Play Again?", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                ships = 3;
                fuel = 100;
                initGame();
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }//end if
        }//end 'no ships' if
    }//end killShip

    private void theForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        fuel--;

        //check to see if user is out of gas
        if (fuel < 0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Out of Fuel!!!");
            fuel += 20;
            killShip();
            initGame();
        }//end if

        //look for arrow keys

        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                picLander.Image = myPics.Images[1];
                dy -= 2;
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                picLander.Image = myPics.Images[2];
                dx++;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                picLander.Image = myPics.Images[3];
                dx--;
                break;
            default:
                //do nothing
                break;
        }//end switch

        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Up && level==2)
        {
            dy -= 3;
        }else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && level== 2)
        {
            dx += 2;
        }else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && level == 2)
        {
            dx -= 2;
        }
    }//end keydown

    private void moveShip()
    {
        //change x and check for boundaries
        x += dx;
        if (x > this.Width - picLander.Width)
        {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(this.Width - picLander.Width);
        }//end if

        //change y and check for boundaries

        y += dy;


        if (y < 0)
        {
            y = Convert.ToDouble(this.Height - picLander.Height);

        }//end if

        if (y > this.Height - picLander.Height)
        {
            y = 0;
        }//end if

        //move picLander to new location
        picLander.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
    }//end MoveShip



    private void theForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }
}
```

Comment: We need you to show us something. What's the Lunar Lander game code?

Comment: @John Ephraim Tugado,The question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Tick' event of the timer.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your code goes here
    }
```

Comment: I use the 'Tick' event of the timer,I do not understand the purpose of the author,In fact, my code is author of the book.

Comment: @john I think it's just to update the stats and to move the rocket. Doesn't it  includes an explanation?

Comment: @john make sure you start the timer to see the effects of your code change.